# Multiple, layered elements inside pattern-element

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently trying to reproduce some patterns from images in SVG. Currently, the patterns reference an image:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" style="contain: strict;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-frontend" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="6" height="6">
            <image href="/assets/img/pattern/frontend.png" x="0" y="0" width="6" height="6">
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Now I'm starting to replace them, but I am running into an issue where it looks like I can only place a single element inside the pattern element. Whatever Element is the first child element will be used and everything else gets ignored:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" style="contain: strict;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-frontend" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
            <rect x="3" y="3" width="1" height="1" fill="green">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" fill="currentcolor" style="fill: var(--color-accent-300)">
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

This will make the green rect visible, but not the other one. If I change the order of the elements, it will make the other one visible and the green one will not be visible.

I feel like I misunderstand something about this, ultimately I would like to be able to set an entire `<rect>` that spans the entirety of the pattern and serve as a background, but that doesn't work at all because it only ever shows one element at a time. And later on I'll need to use multiple elements to create some more complex patterns.

What am I not understanding here? Thankful for any input!

Comment: you need to close the rect tag `<rect x="3" ...... />` instead of  `<rect x="3" ...... >`

Answer (score 0):

It is like @enxaneta pointed out, that I just had a syntax error. The `<rect>`'s need to be self-closing.